# UML Class Diagram Multiplicity

Tags: class, uml, diagram, multiplicity

I have a confusion in UML class diagram Multiplicity.
To ask my question , first i need to give you an example of a situation; Consider this requirement:
"Sections shall have many topics."
I can make the classes for Section and Topic with their multiplicity as follows :

**Example 1)**
[image: Example 1]

The above relation can be read as : "**One or more** sections has many topics".

But consider this design also :

**Example 2)**
[image: Example 2]
The above relation can be read as "One section has many topics , and one topic is in only one section."

**Question 1 is :**
What is the correct design?

Because for me i think the Example 2 design is the correct one, because i am considering only ONE instance at that particular time. But in Example 1 , they considered the Section class as a very high view! (Of course i can make infinity number of instances of any class...)

**Question 2** is : In Example 2, do we say that there exists only **one** Section in the **whole** system, that's why we write it as in Example 1? Also in Example 1, This relation is Many to Many, so we need to make an association class to handle it.

I hope you understood my confusion, thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

**Q1:** In fact it depends on the requirements. A `Topic` can appear in many `Section`s as being discussed under different aspects. If you require that a topic must be completely covered in one section then your 2nd approach would be right. Anyhow, I think that the first is the more common way of doing things.

**Q2:** No. You only say that a `Topic` can have only one `Section`. To tell that there's only one section allowed you'd probably need a constraint. (I used a `<<singleton>>` stereotype for such purposes which is no UML standard, though.)

BTW: you multiplicity in ex. 2 is wrong. To the left you must only have `1..*` and to the right only one `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
For your first answer : Yes it actually meant that the same topic cannot be in more than 1 section. Ex: TopicA cannot be in SectionA and SectionB. The reason why i don't prefer Example 1, because we need to add 1 more association class to link Topic class with Section class (Many to Many relationship) unlike in Example 2. So i don't think we need to make it Many to Many relationship for this task.

For your note : The section might have 0 to many topics, that's why i used * only.

Comment: Your 2nd ex. shows * over 1 to the left. Thats's incorrect. Same with the two stacked 1s to the right.

Answer (score 1):

In example 1 there are two independent statements:

*Every* instance of a section can have any number of topics and

*every* instance of a topic must have at least one section. I don‘t know whether this is what you meant.

PS: The composition, shown by the filled diamond, implies exclusivity. Therefore, the multiplicity can at maximum be 1, not 1..*.

An Association Class is not needed. Many to many relationships are just normal Associations.